# Pandas df reorder rows and columns according to integer index list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following structure for my data frame:

```
          col1    col2   col3
 myindex
 apple    A       B      C
 pear     Ab      Bb     Cb
 turtle   A1      B1     C1
```

Now I get two lists, one with reordered column indices, one with reordered row indices, but as integers, for example `rowindices = [3,1,2]` and `colindices = [1,3,2]`. The data frame should now be reordered according to these indices and then look like this:

```
          col1   col3   col2
 myindex
 turtle   A1     C1     B1
 apple    A      C      B
 pear     Ab     Cb     Bb
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and because python counts from `0` convert list to arrays and subtract `1`:

```
rowindices = [3,1,2]
colindices = [1,3,2]

df = df.iloc[np.array(rowindices)-1, np.array(colindices)-1]
print (df)
        col1 col3 col2
myindex               
turtle    A1   C1   B1
apple      A    C    B
pear      Ab   Cb   Bb
```

If is possible change values in lists solution is simplier:

```
rowindices1 = [2,0,1]
colindices1 = [0,2,1]

df = df.iloc[rowindices1, colindices1]
print (df)
        col1 col3 col2
myindex               
turtle    A1   C1   B1
apple      A    C    B
pear      Ab   Cb   Bb
```